# ASP.NET MVC - Redirect/Post on Dropdown list change. Add to Route Values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown list bound to some Viewdata. When a user changes the value, I'd like to essentially add the value of the dropdown to the routevalue dictionary so it's a parameter but keep the existing routevalues in place.

Right now I've got it so changing the value forces the page to post as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Regions", Nothing, New With {.onchange = "this.form.submit();"})
```

This obviously isn't what I want as I've had to repeat the code in the post section in the controller and I lose the other routevalues.

Is there anyway I can amend the .onchange part so it sends the value of the dropdown through to the routevalues and refreshes the page?

Comment: If you don't want to post to the controller every time, is jquery an option?

Comment: When you are posting the form the data is bound to be lost as HTTP is stateless. Why do you want to achieve that if the requirements is clearer then maybe a better solution could be there.

Comment: @Nikshep - I'm only using the post at the moment as it's the only way I can get close to my requirement.
I'm looking to add the value of the dropdown list to the route values.

Comment: @Rikon - I'm happy to use Jquery if someone can help to ensure the existing RouteValues stay in tact and I can add the additional parameter to them?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up resolving this by manually constructing the parameter string using Javascript and using window.location.